# EAAccessory stops after cordova application is minimized on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I am building an cordova application that connects to a bluetooth reader. Everything is working find when the app is running (not minimized). I am able to read the bluetooth data. If I now minimize the app and then maximize it again (not sure if this is the right term) then I am not able to receive any data anymore. I do see the following in XCode:

> 2015-11-26 12:24:13.944 MyAppName[704:170849]
>   /SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-288.20.7/EAAccessoryManager.m:__51-[EAAccessoryManager
>   _checkForConnectedAccessories]_block_invoke-631 ending background task

I have also tried to implement the accessoryDidConnect and accessoryDidDisconnect using the below code, but both functions never get called:

```
- (void) pluginInitialize
{
    NSLog(@"init called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:selfselector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                               object:nil];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) accessoryDidConnect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    EAAccessory *connectedAccessory = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:EAAccessoryKey];
    NSLog(@"error :%@", connectedAccessory.protocolStrings);
    // Only notify of change if the accessory added has valid protocol strings
    if( connectedAccessory.protocolStrings.count != 0 )
    {
        _accessoryList = [[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories] mutableCopy];
    }
    NSLog(@"connected");
    isDeviceLoaded=true;
}

- (void)accessoryDidDisconnect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //    EAAccessory *disconnectedAccessory = (EAAccessory *)[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"EAAccessorySelectedKey"];
    NSLog(@"disconnected");
    _accessoryList = [[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]mutableCopy];
    isDeviceLoaded=true;
}
```

The pluginInitialize function is called, but accessoryDidConnect or accessoryDidDisconnect is never called. How do I re-connect to the bluetooth reader?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I was missing the following last line inside my plugin:

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```

Here is the full method again:

```
- (void) pluginInitialize
{
    NSLog(@"init called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryDidConnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
                                               object:nil];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(accessoryDidDisconnect:)
                                                 name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];

}
```